# How to fix rss in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, rss

I have version 9.0 installed. Whenever I click on an rss link. I see something like this:
[image]

It doesn't show a whole page of pure code when I do this on firefox, any ideas on how to fix this? Or is Chrome really made to act this way,

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is in fact normal behavior on Chrome. This article complains about it: ["RSS is Dying and You Should Be Very Worried"](http://camendesign.com/blog/rss_is_dying).

There are Chrome Extensions that will handle things for you, however. [Just do a search for RSS in extensions, and it'll turn up many options.](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/search?q=rss) Probably you'll need to decide what you want to happen. One natural thing is to have clicking on an RSS link take you to the subscription page in Google Reader. But you may want something else.

Comment: My first thought after seeing "RSS is Dying" was: _Who cares? We still have Atom._

Comment: The problem covers both kinds of feeds, which are barely different.